# D3 how to select text elements given a specific id attribute

Tags: select, d3.js

I need to select svg text elements that have the 'id' attribute value 's'.

Tried like below but it doesn't help..

```
d3.selectAll("[id=s]").selectAll("text");
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you want to use 'class' instead of id

```
d3.selectAll(".s")
```

Normally, ID is unique to each element.

Answer (score 1):

You're only allowed one element with an id of s per document so

```
d3.select("#s")
```

would select it no matter what it is.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but does it mean we can't do nested selecting in D3? If I want to specifically select a set of text elements that have some unique attribute is there a solution ?

Comment: If the attribute has a unique value then you'll only get one so what's the point of nested selecting.

Answer (score 1):

The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.  So you cannot have multiple text elements with the same id.

To select an element by id and selecting all the text elements within that element :-

```
var texts = d3.select("#id").selectAll("text");
```

To select all text element having an attribute value :-

```
var texts = d3.selectAll("text[attrName=attrValue]");
```

Answer (score -1):

Was able to get this done through this.

```
d3.selectAll("[id=" + id + "]").filter(".someClass");
```